# Do i need to thaw meat before cooking in pressure cooker

Tags: meat, frozen

Do I have to have meat thawed before putting it in my pressure cooker.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the cut of meat - like a a previous answer mentioned - roasts are tricky because of their thickness.  You can still do them but they will get to the fall-apart stage. Meat that does better pressure cooked from frozen includes chicken, ground meat, pork cubes.  I wrote an article about [how to pressure cook frozen meat](http://www.hippressurecooking.com/how-to-pressure-cook-frozen-meat/) that includes the basic procedure for pressure cooking frozen meat plus following tips:

- Brown what you can
- Cover the meat in liquid (boil it)
- The pressure cooker will take longer to reach pressure electric pre.ssure cookers may time-out and need to be re-started
- Increase the cooking time according to thickness (see my [frozen meat pressure cooking time chart](http://www.hippressurecooking.com/pressure-cooking-times/#meat))
- Take the temperature of the meat to make sure the heat penetrated all to the center

So it's possible to pressure cook frozen meat, it'll work in a pinch but I wouldn't do it as a regular thing. ; )

Answer (score 0):

While there's really no danger to this practice, if the cut of meat is large enough you're going to have a problem with the outer layer of the meat being far higher in temperature than the core. I would recommend bringing the entire cooker up to temperature slowly to avoid uneven cooking. At some very large values of 'meatVolume' you're going to run into temp danger zone problems, but I doubt this is a concern at personal consumption sizes.